# Why isn't my background color being applied from CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, background-color

I have a small css issue in my react app, but I can't find a way to fix it.

The background of my div is always white no matter the color I set (Hex, rgb or rgba). Even the border-radius is not working but width/height and margins are working perfectly fine.

Here's my code :

card.js

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/card.css";

export default class Cards extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <img src="../images/cards/BR-Customcard-back.png" alt="card" />
        <span>Card Name</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

card.css :

```
.card {
  background-color: rgba(107, 66, 30, 0.4);
  width: 282px;
  height: 417px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Parent element, cards.js :

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/cards.css";
import Card from "./Card";

export default class Cards extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cards" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
        <Card />
        <Card />
        <Card />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

cards.css

```
.cards {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

rendered css :

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
.card {
    background-color: rgba(107, 66, 30, 0.4);
    width: 282px;
    height: 417px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

rendered markup :

```
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="../images/cards/BR-Customcard-back.png" alt="card">
        <span>Card Name</span>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: What does the rendered markup look like?

Comment: Can you please check if it works without image ? because its very hard to say anyhting without seeing rendered screen. Also there is a possibility of another Card class being overwriting the style, you can use css modules to avoid that so the each one has unique class created by React. Otherwise your code runs just fine, you can check here - https://react-wdeywb.stackblitz.io/

Comment: I tried without the image and the result is the same. I also added the rendered css in my post.

Comment: The issue might be that there are two "card" classes in the rendered version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, I'm using the card class which is already defined in react or bootstrap.
I renamed my class customCard and it's working.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

The class name you set on the component is not the same class name as you defined in the CSS file; it should be:

```
className="card"
```

Comment: The className is ok, card in the js and card in the css. You are looking at the parent cards I think ^^

Comment: hard to say without being able to see your folder structure, but it might be the path to your css file that's causing the issue since non of your styles are being applied

Comment: Path is good also, other styles such as margins and height/width are working.

Comment: try inspect element to see the computed css, if the style you're looking for is crossed out, it means you have another definition (possibly from a library such as bootstrap) overriding your styles. Another quick way to test this is to add ```!important``` to the style that is NOT currently working.

Comment: @AnthonyDa haha I posted the above before I saw your post saying you have it resolved, glad you got it going!